# PDF to PNG conversion with Imagick

Tags: php, imagick, cmyk

I have a webpage where I have many pdf documents that are 1 page images in CMYK. I need to convert them to png/jpg to display it on the webpage. I am trying to use PHP native Imagick but stumbled upon weird issue. Code that does the conversion looks like this:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(200, 200);
$im->readimage($file->getAbsolutePath());
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
$im->writeImage($file->getAbsolutePath() . '.png');
```

Now on my local installation everything works fine, PNG file looks like PDF document. But on my server I noticed that sometimes colors are completely inaccurate.

Here is an example:

[Source pdf](http://zefiryn.jewula.net/uploads/doc.pdf)

[Local convert result](http://zefiryn.jewula.net/uploads/image2.png)

[Server convert result](http://zefiryn.jewula.net/uploads/image1.png)

The only difference I noticed is in Imagick versions reported by phpinfo:

Locally: PHP 5.5.9 Imagick: 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16

Server:  PHP 5.4.42 Imagick: 6.8.9-7 Q16 x86_64 2015-03-21

Do anyone have any idea how to make server use correct color space to convert pdf into png?

[EDIT / UPDATE]

As suggested by @fab-sa I tried to use icc profiles now the code looks like:

```
$icc_cmyk = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/USWebUncoated.icc');
$icc_rgb = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc');
$im->setResolution(200,200);
$im->readimage($file->getAbsolutePath());
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->profileImage('icc', $icc_cmyk);
$im->profileImage('icc', $icc_rgb);
$im->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);
$im->writeImage($file->getAbsolutePath().'.png');
```

And icc profiles:

https://github.com/vivid-planet/library/blob/master/icc/sRGB_v4_ICC_preference.icc

https://github.com/nicolasfranck/Grim/blob/master/profiles/Adobe%20ICC%20Profiles/CMYK%20Profiles/USWebUncoated.icc

However still no expected result.

Comment: Which versions of PHP do you use in local and server ?
Seems to have the same problem : https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59606

Comment: I added php version info to the original post

Comment: I tried using icc profiles but with no success (see update)

Comment: HELLO. I AM USING COMPLETELY DIFFERENT VERSIONS OF SOFTWARE LOCALLY AND ON MY SERVER, AND THEY DO NOT GIVE THE SAME RESULT. WHAT COULD BE THE CAUSE OF THIS?!!ONE!

Comment: Does that supposed to be a helpful comment? I understand that different version may produce different results. In this case conversion is incorrect (which should not be the case as documentation does not contain any information about colorspace changes between versions) so my question is if anyone know or have an idea how to make my server version to work correctly.

Comment: "Does that supposed to be a helpful comment?" No, it's supposed to be sarcasm. You're using running some code against completely different versions of libraries - it's not that surprising there is a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the version of Ghostscript being used on your server is not processing the pdf correctly. I get the same incorrect result with gs version 8.7 and get the correct result with 9.16

#### ghostscript version 8.7

> gs -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=1 -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r50  -sOutputFile=docgs8-%d.png doc.pdf

[image]

#### ghostscript version 9.16 downloaded from http://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

> ./gs-916-linux_x86_64 -q
>
> > -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=1 -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -r50  -sOutputFile=docgs9-%d.png doc.pdf

[image]